# Knapsack - How to identify which weights are used?

Tags: c++, knapsack-problem

I have a code which gives the maximum value I can get by filling the knapsack with the optimal set of weights.

```
int arr[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int Weight[5] = {2, 5, 8, 7, 9};
int Value[5]  = {4, 5, 7, 9, 8};
const int n = 5;
const int maxCapacity = 20;

int maximum(int a, int b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

int knapsack(int capacity, int i)
{
    if (i > n-1) return 0;

    if (capacity < Weight[i])
    {
        return knapsack(capacity, i+1);
    }
    else
    {
        return maximum (knapsack(capacity, i+1),
                        knapsack(capacity - Weight[i], i+1) + Value[i]);
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    cout<<knapsack(maxCapacity,0)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I need to extend this solution by printing which all weights are used to find the optimal solution. For this I plan to use an array arr initialized to 0. Whenever a weight is used I mark the corresponding position in arr by 1, otherwise it remains 0.

First thing that came into my mind is to change the maximum() function like shown below

```
int maximum(int a, int b, int i)
{
    if (a > b)
    {
        if (arr[i] == 1) arr[i] = 0;
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        if (arr[i] == 0) arr[i] = 1;
        return b;
    }
}
```

But even this solution fails for some combination of weights and values. Any suggestions on how to go forward?

Comment: You could post an example combination which fails, it's usually very illustrative.

Comment: PS: you should consider substituting those arrays with `std::array<T>` if you are using C++11, much more convenient.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Example array is already hard coded in the code. In this case weights - 2, 7, 9 will be used and final value of arr[5] is {1, 1, 0, 1, 1} where as it should have been {1, 0, 0, 1, 1}

Comment: If you're going to define a `const int n = 5` you may as well use it to establish your array size.

Comment: @Aesthete: I know. Actual code is not this. Arrays are not hard coded in the actual code. I simplified it to post here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you dont know which one of the two options are selected by this command

```
return maximum (knapsack(capacity, i+1),
                knapsack(capacity - Weight[i], i+1) + Value[i]);
```

I guess you can use two variables to store the values and if the weight is selected( the value of that variable is bigger ) you can add it to the array . Hope that solves your problem.